# WPF: bind to an object's property; what happens when the object changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let's say you have an object with a property and a control that is binding to a property of that object.  What happens when that object is changed?

For example, ViewModel:

```
public class TheViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private TheObjectClass theObject;
        public TheObjectClass TheObject
        {
            get { return theObject; }
            set { theObject = value; 
                  OnPropertyChanged("TheObject"); }
        }
}
```

The object's class:

```
public class TheObjectClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private ThePropertyClass theProperty;
        public ThePropertyClass TheProperty
        {
            get { return theProperty; }
            set { theProperty= value; 
                  OnPropertyChanged("TheProperty"); }
        }
}
```

The property's class:

```
public class ThePropertyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private object objectToBindTo;
        public object ObjectToBindTo
        {
            get { return objectToBindTo; }
            set { objectToBindTo= value; 
                  OnPropertyChanged("ObjectToBindTo"); }
        }
}
```

And then in a window (that has the ViewModel set as it's DataContext) you have a control that binds to this object, like:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding TheObject.TheProperty.ObjectToBindTo}/>
```

Then you reset ViewModel.TheObject somewhere (after the binding has been made):

```
ViewModel.TheObject = new TheObjectClass();
```

In my testing (not specifically of this code, which is just a simplified example of the code in my application) it seems that sometimes the Binding survives, and sometimes it stops working.  What should I expect to happen here?  It seems logical to me that the property binding would break when the parent object is instantiated to a different object, but sometimes it seems to survive which is really confusing me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, this is a supported operation, and the binding should always "survive".  The WPF binding system sees the property changed notification on `TheObject`, and should reset the binding to the new subobjects.

In practice, the binding will occasionally not survive, but this is normally because there is  a point in time where one object along the chain becomes `null`, which then breaks the binding.  If one object becomes `null`, WPF effectively unsubscribes from the `PropertyChanged` call (as there's no object to listen on), and never sees the new value get set, which in turn can prevent it from functioning.

Comment: @JPProgrammer "In practice, the binding will occasionally not survive" ... So how can you avoid/prevent the binding from being broken in the case where one object in the chain is null?

Comment: @blt Other than not having an object in the chain become null, I'm not 100% sure, actually.  I've mostly had to get the top level binding to refresh, which causes it to find it again...