# Change binded null object to some data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

### problem

I have a 2d array of some objects. For greater flexibility, it is an array of interface types. At the start, some cells can be null, but it fills with data later. I bind this array to UniformGrid in WPF. When I create a new object and add it in the array my grid doesn't change. The question is how to design bindind that if bound objects change (not the properties in object), the grid will change too.

Similar question was [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126157/wpf-bind-to-an-objects-property-what-happens-when-the-object-changes)
but without decisions

### **my code**

*cells in array*
(simple classes with method that can change properties to be sure binding works correctly. nothing special here)

```
interface IOrg
{
    string Text { get; }
    SolidColorBrush SolidColor { get; }
    void SetColor();
    void SetText();
}

class IOrgA : IOrg
{
    Random random;

    public IOrgA(Random random)
    {
        SolidColor = new SolidColorBrush();

        this.random = random;
        SetColor();
        SetText();
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public SolidColorBrush SolidColor { get; private set; }

    public void SetColor()
    {
        SolidColor.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, (byte)random.Next(256));
    }

    public void SetText()
    {
        Text = random.Next(1000).ToString();
    }
}

class IOrgB : IOrg
{
    Random random;

    public IOrgB(Random random)
    {
        SolidColor = new SolidColorBrush();

        this.random = random;
        SetColor();
        SetText();
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public SolidColorBrush SolidColor { get; private set; }

    public void SetColor()
    {
        SolidColor.Color = Color.FromRgb((byte)random.Next(256), 255, 255);
    }

    public void SetText()
    {
        Text = random.Next(1000, 2000).ToString();
    }
}
```

*main class*

```
class Table
{
    //array with data
    private IOrg[,] _layer;
    private Random _random = new Random();

    public Table(int heigth, int width)
    {
        Height = heigth;
        Widht = width;

        _layer = new IOrg[heigth, width];
        ListLayer = new List<List<IOrg>>();

        FillLayer();
        FillList();
    }

    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Widht { get; private set; }
    //list for binding
    public List<List<IOrg>> ListLayer { get; private set; }

    void FillLayer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Widht; j++)
            {
                //randomly fill array
                if (_random.Next(30) == 1)
                {
                    IOrg org;

                    if (_random.Next(2) == 0)
                    {
                        org = new IOrgA(_random);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        org = new IOrgB(_random);
                    }

                    _layer[i, j] = org;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*xaml*

```
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- size of uniform gris -->
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="GridSize" >50</sys:Int32>

    <!-- template for each row -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDataTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ElementDataTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid x:Name="RowGrid" Columns="{StaticResource GridSize}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- template for each element in row -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ElementDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, FallbackValue=__}">
            <TextBlock.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SolidColor.Color, FallbackValue=#123456}"></SolidColorBrush>
            </TextBlock.Background>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="14*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lst"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource RowDataTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid x:Name="World" Rows="{StaticResource GridSize}" Background="Bisque"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Height="50" Click="Button_Click">
        button
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

*binding*

```
table = new Table(50, 50);
lst.ItemsSource = table.ListLayer;
```

I randomly fill my array with data, bind it in UniformGrid, and provide FallbackValue for null value objects. When I add a new object to the array, nothing changes. How do Ifix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `List` as below, try with an `ObservableCollection` instead.

`public List<List<IOrg>> ListLayer { get; private set; }`

At any point, if you need to add an object to the collection, just raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which your ViewModel(DataContext) class needs to implement.